# Executing example on Giraph1.1.0 on hadoop 2.3.0-cdh-5.0.shows the following error

Tags: hadoop, giraph

```
root@pseudo-hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop# bin/hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op output/shortestpaths -w 1
14/06/12 17:32:32 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one.
14/06/12 17:32:32 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format specified. Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one.
14/06/12 17:32:32 INFO job.GiraphJob: run: Since checkpointing is disabled (default), do not allow any task retries (setting mapred.map.max.attempts = 0, old value = 4)
14/06/12 17:32:32 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/06/12 17:32:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:8020/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/root/.staging/job_201406121249_0012
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(BspOutputFormat.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:948)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:582)
    at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:250)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first warnings don't matter.

A java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError suggests you have built Giraph against the wrong version of Hadoop.  Try building using the correct profile, e.g. **mvn -Phadoop_2.0.0 package**

Comment: Is there no other way to make it work with my current version of Hadoop 2.3.0 without uninstalling this version of Giraph or downgrading to a lower version of Hadoop?

Comment: Hadoop 1 and Hadoop 2 have completely different packages structures.  If Giraph thinks it's running on Hadoop 1 it will look for things that don't exist in Hadoop 2, and there's no way it can work.